# Sorting array data with a combine date and time in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have array like below, how to sort data with a combination of date and time descending?

```
$manifest = array(
    array("date"=>2019-02-21,"time"=>04:49:54,"desc"=>"arrived in indonesia"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-25,"time"=>04:02:21,"desc"=>"arrived in soppeng"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-22,"time"=>01:42:51,"desc"=>"arrived in makassar"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-22,"time"=>02:42:51,"desc"=>"arrived in makassar gateway"),
);
```

Expected result:

```
$manifest = array(
    array("date"=>2019-02-25,"time"=>04:02:21,"desc"=>"arrived in soppeng"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-22,"time"=>02:42:51,"desc"=>"arrived in makassar gateway"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-22,"time"=>01:42:51,"desc"=>"arrived in makassar"),
    array("date"=>2019-02-21,"time"=>04:49:54,"desc"=>"arrived in indonesia")
    );
```

Thanks For Help

Comment: Show us, what you have tried so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: @AbuAyyub Did you try use `array_multisort` as in my post?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: @04fs this is not duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my self, i am using

```
usort($manifest,function($a,$b){
   return strtotime($b['date']." ".$b['time']) - strtotime($a['date']." ".$a['time']);
});
```

Thanks for all to helping me.

Comment: You can mark your's answer as accepted so it will shown this issue has been resolve (or other answer if you prefer any)

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = $manifest;

usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
  $ad = new DateTime($a['date'] ." ". $a['time']);
  $bd = new DateTime($b['date']." ". $a['time']);

  if ($ad == $bd) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $ad < $bd ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rsort()` which will sort the array in descending order.

```
<?php
$manifest = array(
  array("date"=>"2019-02-21","time"=>"04:49:54","desc"=>"arrived in indonesia"),
  array("date"=>"2019-02-25","time"=>"04:02:21","desc"=>"arrived in soppeng"),
  array("date"=>"2019-02-22","time"=>"01:42:51","desc"=>"arrived in makassar"),
  array("date"=>"2019-02-22","time"=>"02:42:51","desc"=>"arrived in makassar gateway")
);

rsort($manifest);

echo '<pre>';print_r($manifest);echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-02-25
            [time] => 04:02:21
            [desc] => arrived in soppeng
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-02-22
            [time] => 02:42:51
            [desc] => arrived in makassar gateway
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-02-22
            [time] => 01:42:51
            [desc] => arrived in makassar
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2019-02-21
            [time] => 04:49:54
            [desc] => arrived in indonesia
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [array-multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)?

```
array_multisort(array_column($manifest, 'date'), SORT_DESC, array_column($manifest, 'time'), SORT_DESC, $manifest);
```

Simple as that